# There are no fitted values for the final model when using train from CARET

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret

Here is the code:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv",number = 5, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, classProbs=T, savePredictions = T, verboseIter = T)
    grid=expand.grid(.trials=c(1,100),.model=c("tree","rules"),.winnow=c(T,F))
    m=train(Category1 ~ ., data = tr.bal,method="C5.0", metric="ROC",trControl=ctrl, tuneGrid=grid)
```

I thought there would be a fitted values column under m$finalModel. But I don't see any, or am I missing something? So how do I get the predicted value for the final model? I want to compute ROC thereafter.

Sample data is below:

```
 structure(list(production_year = c(2009L, 2011L, 2011L, 2010L,  2011L, 2010L), movie_sequel = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), creative_type = structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("other", "mainstream"), class = "factor"),
    source = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("based", 
    "other", "Original Screenplay"), class = "factor"), production_method = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("other", "Live Action"), class = "factor"), 
    genre = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Action", 
    "Adventure", "other", "Comedy", "Drama", "Romantic Comedy", 
    "Thriller/Suspense"), class = "factor"), language = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("other", "English"), class = "factor"), 
    movie_board_rating_display_name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("other", "PG", "PG-13", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    movie_release_pattern_display_name = structure(c(7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Exclusive", "Expands Wide", 
    "IMAX", "Limited", "Oscar Qualifying Run", "Special Engagement", 
    "Wide"), class = "factor"), Category1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("nothit", "hit"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("production_year",  "movie_sequel", "creative_type", "source", "production_method",  "genre", "language", "movie_board_rating_display_name", "movie_release_pattern_display_name",  "Category1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the fitted values from a model of class `train` from the caret package by using the `predict` function. You could then use `pROC::roc` to come up with a ROC curve.

```
    p = predict(m)
    curve = pROC::roc(tr.bal$Category1, as.numeric(p))
    plot(curve)
```

Or as a reproducible example:

```
    library(caret)
    data(mtcars)

    ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv",number = 5, 
         summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, classProbs=T, 
         savePredictions = T, verboseIter = T)

    grid=expand.grid(trials=c(1,100),
         model=c("tree","rules"),winnow=c(T,F))
    m=train(factor(am) ~ ., data = mtcars,
            method="C5.0",metric="ROC",
            trControl=ctrl, tuneGrid=grid)
    predict(m)
    library(pROC)
    curve = roc(response = factor(mtcars$am), 
                predictor = as.numeric(predict(m)))
    plot(curve)
```

Annoyingly the roc function wants a numeric vector rather than a factor hence `as.numeric`.

Comment: thanks for this. yes your example could predict the prob. but when im doing the same thing i get an error (undefined columns selected) or is it because of the fact that my final model has specification model = tree, which would be imply no predictions. Also i suppose this must be the final model that the model chooses!

Comment: Does your response have a numeric encoding? Caret throws a warning about variable names when the response is 0/1 in my above reproducible example which prohibits the probability calculation. On switching it to have factor labels the probabilities can be calculated no problem. I also forced the final model to be `tree` and can still generate the predictions. Try changing the labels of the response and see if that works. Otherwise update your question with a reproducible example containing a subset of your data using `dput` and I will have another look. It is the final model that is chosen.

Comment: ya for numeric class it is giving an error so i converted my response into character factor class and it worked. Still my model is not working.

Comment: If you update your question with an example of the data that will help to iron out what the trouble is, use something like `dput(tr.bal[1:100,])` and add the result to your question

Comment: When you say your model is not working what do you mean by this? What sort of error are you getting. In your small reproducible example I get issues because there are only `"hit"` responses in the variable of interest. This gives an error saying `There were missing values in resampled performance measures.` Is this what you have when running on your full data set? Or do you get a different error?

Comment: Models working fine its just that i am not able to predict using the model object, m. let me see if can get more data.